# In libgdx How can I get current date?

Tags: date, time, libgdx

In libgdx How can I get current date?

I found that I can get the time like this:

```
long time = System.nanoTime();
long seconds = time / 1E9;
long minutes = seconds / 60;
long hours = minutes / 60;
```

How can I get current\today date?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Date date = new Date(TimeUtils.millis());
```

Comment: and its cross platform? libgdx can translate it to other platforms?

Comment: [Apparently](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/TimeUtils.html#millis--) it is: _Wrapper around System.nanoTime() and System.currentTimeMillis(). Use this if you want to be compatible across all platforms!_

Answer (score 2):

`System.nanoTime();` returns the time in nanoseconds. There is no need to use it. But if you went that route it would be better to get time in milliseconds: `System.currentTimeMillis();` or use LIBGDX `TimeUtils.millis();` — it returns the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

You still need to translate this time into a normal form. To seconds — divide by 1000. To minutes — divide again by 60. To hours — divide again by 24. And to cut unnecessary days (hours, minutes), use the remainder of the division %24 or %60.

But in this case, you will get GMT. No correction for time zone. On the real devices time will differ from the true.

Much more efficient and easier to use the standard Java calendar:

```
Date date = new Date();
Calendar calendarG = new GregorianCalendar();
calendarG.setTime(date);

int minutes = calendarG.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int hours = calendarG.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

And do not use it inside the RENDER method. The line `Date date = new Date();` generates a lot of garbage.